# Why shall we study mechanics after newtons laws of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, kinematics

I have heard and read that the 3 laws of motion are sufficient to solve any problem in classical mechanics, if its true then why we study concepts like work energy, conservation of momentum, centre of mass, etc. Thanks

Comment: Why would you keep writing texts after you've learned how to write every letter?

Comment: Would you rather use Newton's laws on *every single* particle in an object, instead of "averaging" it down to Centre-of-mass? And remember how easier it all gets with energy conservation calculations where you don't care about directions, sine/cosine etc. New ways to do same things tend to become mainstream simply because they are easier.

Comment: In physics we don't just care about computing and solving problems; we also care about finding a new interpretation, or conceptual insight. Not only do those additional concepts you listed make calculations easier, they also give us a different way to view a problem.

Comment: Yes, it is true that Newton's laws of motion are sufficient to solve any problem in classical mechanics.

Answer (score 2):

Because they make it easier. Deriving everything from first principles every single time would become a massive waste of effort.
(and unfortunately I can tell you it is definitely not how to score in exams.)